# AC divider circuit used to charge a capacitor

Tags: ltspice, voltage-divider, charger

The following circuit uses a capacitive divider network along with a diode rectifier to charge a capacitor. I assumed that once C2 is charged to its maximum( calculated to be around 14mV) the diode and C2 will behave as if it is independent of the divider. But it was seen that the voltage Vx was found to be clamped to negative voltage region. Why is this occuring?
[image]

Comment: Because you can't extract DC from that circuit very effectively. If you made the 45 pF capacitors more like 45 nF and ran the simulation for longer, you might start to see a DC voltage appearing across the 1 uF.

Comment: @Andyaka can u explain this in terms of current flow. It would be very helpful.

Comment: Simulate it. That is what I recommend.

Comment: @Andyaka I simulated and it was observed 1 uF capacitor charges to 14mV and stays there for 45pF case itself. I thought that after that 1uF wont draw any current and hence the voltage divider should work as normal(i.e a normal scaled down sine wave at Vx). But what is the reason for the occurrence of this clamped sine wave at Vx?

Comment: Because you can't extract DC from that circuit very effectively. Try putting a diode from the capacitor junction to ground (anode to ground).

Comment: @Andyaka You mean like a half wave voltage doubler?.Will try that . But can you explain using charge flow why this waveform is occuring at Vx. Just for understanding only. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But can you explain using charge flow why this waveform is occuring at
> Vx. Just for understanding only. Thanks – Hyde*

Simplify the circuit: -

[image]

I've combined (with absolutely no loss of functionality or performance) the three 45 pF capacitors into one 135 pF capacitor. To do this I must also reduce the input voltage of this equivalent circuit from 311 volts pk to 104 volts pk.

Can you see why trying to charge the 1 uF capacitor from the source via a capacitor that is 7,407 times lower in value will take some time and doesn't happen instantly?

---

If you connected a diode to Vx and ground (anode to ground), it forces Vx to stay at a positive value for much longer in the AC cycle and charges the output capacitor more strongly. In effect, the added diode allows conduction through the capacitor (135 pF) when the AC signal goes negative as well as when the AC signal is positive (current through the existing D1 diode).

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. But in simulation it is not taking long time to charge, rather in 1/4th of the time period C2 charges to 14mV and remains there. When i kept 135nF then it charged to around 12.5V in the same time and is remaining constant. Why is this happening? Also how does connecting a diode between divider junction and ground improves the charging?

Comment: 135 nF? Did you use 135 nF or pF?

Comment: I tried with both. For 135pF it is saturating at 14mV whereas for 135nF it is saturating at 12V

Comment: You also have to consider that the diode has capacitance and losses. Try modeling an ideal diode or replacing with a schottky diode.

Comment: So is the generic capacitance in LTSpice having any non idealities?

Comment: I don't use LTSpice but I doubt it.